# how install fos CommentBundle on symfony 2.7.5 that that use fos\RestBundle ^2.0@dev

Tags: composer-php, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle, symfony-2.7, foscommentbundle

I use `symfony 2.7.5-dev` and install `FOSRestBundle` and `JMSSerilizerBundle` on it that installed version `FOSRestBundle` and `JMSSerializerbundle` is `dev-master`.
my `composer.json:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
...
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
    ...
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.0@dev",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "^1.1@dev",
    ...
```

I try install bundle by `composer require friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle`  command, i add `"minimum-stability": "dev"` to `composer.json`, but that can not install and raise this errors:

```
Problem 1
- friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle v2.0.7 requires jms/serializer-bundle ~0.11 -> no matching package found.
- friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle v2.0.6 requires jms/serializer-bundle ~0.11 -> no matching package found.
- friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle v2.0.5 requires friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle >=0.11,<0.13-dev -> no matching package found.
- friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle v2.0.4 requires friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle 0.11.*@dev -> no matching package found.
- friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle 2.0.x-dev requires jms/serializer-bundle ~0.11 -> no matching package found.
- friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle v2.0.0 requires symfony/symfony 2.1.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[2.1.x-dev].
- friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle v2.0.1 requires symfony/symfony 2.1.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[2.1.x-dev].
- friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle v2.0.2 requires symfony/symfony 2.1.*@stable -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[2.1.x-dev].
- friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle v2.0.3 requires symfony/symfony 2.1.*@stable -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[2.1.x-dev].
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony 2.1.x-dev
- Installation request for friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle ^2.0@dev -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle[2.0.x-dev, v2.0.0, v2.0.1, v2.0.2, v2.0.3, v2.0.4, v2.0.5, v2.0.6, v2.0.7].

Potential causes:
- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: I fork repository and update composer & controller, now it work on symfony 2.7 https://github.com/ghanbari/FOSCommentBundle

Comment: Could you post it as a answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could install `FOSCommentBundle` by forking of repository & change depedencies (`FOSRestBundle` & `JMSSerializerBundle`) version to latest version.

I need change a few code in `ThreadController`, `RouteRedirectView` class is removed in new version of `FOSRestBundle` and we instead of this class must use `createRouteRedirect` method of `View` class.

[My repository on github](https://github.com/ghanbari/FOSCommentBundle)